# Masonry is loaded but not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-masonry

I have set the Masonry demo on [this page](http://memeqc.com/memes.php).

I see that the plugin loads fine, with no errors. I have defined the column width, but it still doesn't work.

I looked for hours and couldn't find anything wrong?! Do you see what the problem is?

Comment: You're loading jQuery twice. `google.load("jquery", "1.7.1");` and `<script .. src='<snip>jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>`. You have `itemSelector : '.box',`, but your elements have the class `.box2`. You've been looking for hours? :)

Comment: @thirtydot Oh the .box2 thing was cause I was testing, but it not working even with this corrected. And i'ts based on wordpress, even if jquery is loaded twice (I'm trying to remove the extra one), all my jquery calls works. I even do a console.log... ?

Comment: jQuery Masonry is now working on your page. Make the images narrower or the container of your images wider, and you'll see. :/

Comment: But I give columnWidth, it is supposed to resize images/blocks to fit 125px width?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

according to the documentation here: masonry docs, your css itemSelector class needs to specify a width and float left. you have the float defined, but i don't see the width rule. also, since you have images in the anchor tags within your itemSelector, it would be a good idea to make sure those widths are the same as the itemSelector width.

Answer (score 0):

based on your markup, you need to specify class "box2" in your masonry options.
so you should try:

```
$container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '.box2',
    columnWidth: 125
});
```

try that and see if you get success.

Comment: Actually I was making a test, sorry, but now it's corrected and still doesnt work. My console.log pops out, so it's going throught.

Comment: according to the documentation here: [masonry docs](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/intro.html), your css itemSelector class needs to specify a width and float left.  you have the float defined, but i don't see the width rule.  also, since you have images in the anchor tags within your itemSelector, it would be a good idea to make sure those widths are the same as the itemSelector width.

Comment: Ok it works. But now, why does it remain on 2 columns and doesnt take container width?

Comment: Ok i got it to work finally. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you! :)

Comment: i think the masonry demo works when you add padding and margin to your itemSelector element.